# Compilers: How to see "the number of grammars where there exists a string that has at least two different left-most derivations"?

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, parsers

Could someone tell why "G1 and G3 are ambiguous" and how to see whether a string has at least two different left-most derivations in general?

[image: Problem]

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the problem of detecting whether a grammar is ambiguous is, in general, undecidable, for toy grammars like this it is usually pretty easy to find ambiguities by simply enumerating the possible (left-most) derivations until you derive the same sentence in two ways.

For example, $G_1$ has just three productions $S\to a S b \mid S b \mid c$, and none of them has more than one non-terminal on the right hand side. So there are only four derivations of three steps, and it's easy to see that two produce the same sentence.

$$\begin{align}S&\to a S b \to a a S b b \to a a c b b \; (P_1, P_1, P_3)\\
S&\to a S b \to a S b b \to a c b b\; (P_1, P_2, P_3) \\ 
S&\to S b \to a S b b \to a c b b\; (P_2, P_1, P_3) \\
S&\to S b \to S b b \to c b b\; (P_2, P_2, P_3)\\
\end{align}
$$

$G_3$ does have a production which produces two non-terminals, so there are a lot more short derivations. Even so, it shouldn't take you very long to find two derivations for the same sentence.

Proving that a grammar is *not* ambiguous is not so easy. One possibility is to create a conflict-free parsing table, using any standard algorithm. Not all unambiguous grammars are deterministic (and fewer are deterministic with a single lookahead) but if you do manage to find a conflict-free parser, then the grammar was definitely unambiguous.